# How to return struct declared in the same class with function?

Tags: c++, function, class, visual-c++, struct

I have a class declaration in my header file like shown below. One function uses one of the struct as input and the other one as return parameter. The point is when I use in this way compiler gives me error.

What would be the reason ? Any idea is appreciated.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace My_Functions
{
    class My_Functions
    {

    public:
        struct {

            char input_a;
            int input_b;
            double input_c;
            double input_d;
            double input_e;
            double input_f;
            double input_g;

        } Input_Parameters;

        struct {

            char output_a;
            int output_b;
            double output_c;
            double output_d;
            int output_e;

        } Output_Parameters;

    public:
        Output_Parameters FindExit(Input_Parameters input);


    };

}
```

in cpp file

```
My_Functions::Output_Parameters My_Functions::FindExit(My_Functions::Input_Parameters input)
{

}
```

Comment: There's a difference between `struct {} X` and `struct X {}`.

Comment: You declared variables anonymous structs and the names are Output_Parameters, and Input_Parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to fix your problem.

A. `struct struct_name {};` -> This declare structure called 'structure_name'

B. `typedef struct {}struct_name;` -> using `typedef` before your structure will be useful if you don't want to use '`struct`' keyword before name.

C. Use `struct` keyword in function prototype.

```
struct Output_Parameters FindExit(struct Input_Parameters input);
```

Ex for A:

```
    struct Input_Parameters {

        char input_a;
        int input_b;
        double input_c;
        double input_d;
        double input_e;
        double input_f;
        double input_g;

    } ;

    struct Output_Parameters{

        char output_a;
        int output_b;
        double output_c;
        double output_d;
        int output_e;

    };
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit LOL.. No no. I thought these definitions are self explanatory. I will add some explanation now.

Comment: I think if they were self-explanatory to the OP then he wouldn't have posted the question ;)

Comment: "using typedef before your structure will be useful if you don't want to use 'struct' keyword before name"  You already don't have to do that in C++, and on a related note your `C` answer is actually wrong. Otherwise better :)