# Unexpected behavior string literal

Tags: c++, qt

I have two methods:

```
ind addFilter(ind column, const QString & condition);
ind addFilter(ind column, bool condition);
```

When I use this construction gcc choose second method (with `bool condition`)

```
filters->addFilter(familyNameInd, "М*");
```

Why `std::string` convert to bool instead of QString? Or can I specify all string literals to be QString at compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences)

> 2 When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as
>   defined in 13.3.3.1) — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is
>   a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence
>   or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and ...

Relative to your example converting to bool is a standard implicit conversion. So it s better than user-defined conversion using a conversion constructor.
So if you want that the overloaded function with parameter of type `const QString &` would be called you have to specify explicitly the conversion from the string literal to a temporary object of type `QString:`QString( "М*" )`.

Comment: @lpapp What is wrong? If you want to specify a string literal as an argument you have to apply the QString constructor to the argument expression. In this case a temporary object will be created.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: it is better to use QStringLiteral for string literals. QString is not the right call for those.

Comment: @lpapp I do not see a great difference in this case.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Let us leave it with that if you do not know what they really are. I hope the OP at least reads the answers, too.

Comment: @lpapp The question is not about Qt. The question is about why one overloaded function was selected instead of other overloaded function.

Comment: Really? It is tagged as Qt, plus these look like Qt questions to me: `Why std::string convert to bool instead of QString? Or can I specify all string literals to be QString at compilation?`.

Comment: @lpapp I do not see any sense to continue the discussion. The problem was that the compiler selected another overloaded function instead of desired. And some explanation of this are useful. The question was marked with Qt only because some of overloaded functions has a parameter of type QString and nothing more.

Comment: @lpapp I'm already mark this answer as right answer. Don't you think that you probably miss understand question?

Comment: [Remember for a comment in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843564/how-to-return-struct-declared-in-the-same-class-with-function/20843623#comment31263867_20843623).

Comment: @anion155: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers).

Answer (score 2):

"M*" is a const char* which is convertible to a bool due to implicit conversion rules.
The implicit conversion will be chosen over the QString class.

You are going to have to call the function like this:

```
filters->addFilter(familyNameInd, QString("М*"));
```

To avoid an unnecessary copy of the QString, consider using the QStringLiteral macro as well:

```
filters->addFilter(familyNameInd, QStringLiteral("М*"));
```

Comment: Thanks, Captain Obvious. )

Comment: The string literal `"M*"` is **not** a `const char *`. It's a `const char[3]` array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is broken. There is no such an argument and return type as `ind`. I will assume that you meant `int`.

Secondly, POD types have precedence over custom types in C++ when it comes to implicit conversion.

> Why std::string convert to bool instead of QString?

I do not know why you think it would be `std::string`. It simply is not, not even in C++. It is the good old const char[X] where X happens to be three in your case (two letters + terminating nil).

> Or can I specify all string literals to be QString at compilation?

No, but you ought to use this in any case when dealing with string literals in Qt regardless of this situation:

```
filters->addFilter(familyNameInd, QStringLiteral("М*"));
```

For raw string literals like this, please do *not* use the `QString` contructor. It is pointless. Therefore, you would be writing something like this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int addFilter(int column, const QString & condition) { qDebug() << "Test 1"; }
int addFilter(int column, bool condition) { qDebug() << "Test 2"; }

int main()
{
    addFilter(0, QStringLiteral("foo"));
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
Test 1
```

Comment: typedef unsigned int ind; // reduction of the index

Comment: @anion155: yiiiikes. First of all, it is superfluous obfuscation. Secondly, it should be quint rather than unsigned int. Thirdly, indices are _ints_, not _unsigned ints_ in the Qt API.